# How to make work 'wp_set_script_translations' function automatically?

Tags: php, wordpress, wpml

I'm trying to make 'wp_set_script_translations' work with theme in conjunction with wpml.

I had implemented all the recommendations from Wordpress Codex. WPML plugin generates file in format "locale-domain-handle.json" in "\wp-content\languages\wpml" folder. But file generates without translations and with wrong domain name "messages" instead domain that I specified. Also I checked WPML String Translation files and it seems that wrong json generates by JED function that always sets "message" domain and ignores customer domain name.

```
{
  "translation-revision-date": "2019-04-23 08:33:37+0000",
  "generator": "WPML String Translation 2.10.2",
  "domain": "messages",
  "locale_data": {
    "messages": {
      "": {
        "domain": "messages",
        "plural-forms": "nplurals=2; plural=n != 1;",
        "lang": "fr_FR"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to see the translations with right domain name in the file or alternative and automated method without manual generation of translation files.

Comment: It seems that using `messages` as text domain is correct. Maybe you are experiencing some issues with the JSON file MD5 hash. Have a look here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/415545/231798

Answer (score 0):

Translation has finally been properly developed and documented: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/internationalization/

Basically, you need to:

1. Use the wp-i18n package to define which are the strings in your project to be translatable.
2. Compile your code (`wp i18n make-pot` will search for translation strings in your compiled code, not in your source).
3. Use the WP-CLI (`wp i18n make-pot`) to create a `.pot` file, just like we've always used with WP themes and plugins.
4. Generate a `.po` file based on our previously created `.pot` and translate its content.
5. Use the WP-CLI again (`wp i18n make-json`) to convert our `.po` file to the JSON format needed.
6. Use the `wp_set_script_translations` PHP function to load the translation files.

Hope this helps someone out there ;)