# How to make Gutenberg Block Translation work?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I've just built a Gutenberg block, and I'd like to have it translated into different languages. I am using my WordPress in Portuguese and I've made a Portuguese translation. I followed all the steps available in the documentation https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/internationalization/ and it still didn't work.

My plugin is called `spoiler-alert`.

I have created a `.pot` file named `spoileralert.pot` in the `/spoiler-alert/languages` folder. Then, I've generated the md5 files and even created a new file with all my strings using a script handler. My languages folder structure looks like this:

```
languages
- spoileralert.pot
- spoileralert-pt_BR.po
- spoileralert-pt_BR-<HASH-CODE-1>.json
- spoileralert-pt_BR-<HASH-CODE-2>.json
- spoileralert-pt_BR-<HASH-CODE-3>.json
- spoileralert-pt_BR-spoileralert.json
```

And here is my PHP file `spoiler-alert.php`:

```
function spoiler_alert_spoiler_alert_block_init() {
    $dir = dirname( __FILE__ );

    $script_asset_path = "$dir/build/index.asset.php";
    if ( ! file_exists( $script_asset_path ) ) {
        throw new Error(
            'You need to run `npm start` or `npm run build` for the "spoiler-alert/spoiler-alert" block first.'
        );
    }
    $index_js     = 'build/index.js';
    $script_asset = require( $script_asset_path );
    wp_register_script(
        'spoiler-alert-spoiler-alert-block-editor',
        plugins_url( $index_js, __FILE__ ),
        $script_asset['dependencies'],
        $script_asset['version']
    );

    $editor_css = 'build/index.css';
    wp_register_style(
        'spoiler-alert-spoiler-alert-block-editor',
        plugins_url( $editor_css, __FILE__ ),
        array(),
        filemtime( "$dir/$editor_css" )
    );

    $style_css = 'build/style-index.css';
    wp_register_style(
        'spoiler-alert-spoiler-alert-block',
        plugins_url( $style_css, __FILE__ ),
        array(),
        filemtime( "$dir/$style_css" )
    );

    register_block_type( 'spoiler-alert/spoiler-alert', array(
        'editor_script' => 'spoiler-alert-spoiler-alert-block-editor',
        'editor_style'  => 'spoiler-alert-spoiler-alert-block-editor',
        'style'         => 'spoiler-alert-spoiler-alert-block',
    ) );


    wp_set_script_translations( 'spoileralert', 'spoiler-alert', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/languages' );

}
add_action( 'init', 'spoiler_alert_spoiler_alert_block_init' );
```

In my `.js` files I've imported the translation package using: `import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';`

And I am using the translations like: `title: __( 'Spoiler Alert', 'spoiler-alert' ),`

How can I make the translation display correctly?

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while already, but it might still be useful to you or someone else out there. I'm simply copying and pasting what I've already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62260324/1374576).

I've been through this process quite a few times already, so I'm 100% sure this is working properly. Carefully go through each one of the steps and you should manage to solve any issues you might be running into ;)

Translation has finally been properly developed and documented: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/internationalization/

Basically, you need to:

1. Use the wp-i18n package to define which are the strings in your project to be translatable.
2. Compile your code (`wp i18n make-pot` will search for translation strings in your compiled code, not in your source).
3. Use the WP-CLI (`wp i18n make-pot`) to create a `.pot` file, just like we've always used with WP themes and plugins.
4. Generate a `.po` file based on our previously created `.pot` and translate its content.
5. Use the WP-CLI again (`wp i18n make-json`) to convert our `.po` file to the JSON format needed.
6. Use the `wp_set_script_translations` PHP function to load the translation files.